# Can't open .exe file

Tags: permissions, 22.04, wine

my `.exe` file is not opening, i did not have execute permission so i changed the permission by `chmod +x`. Still i can't open the file with **wine** and using `./` too, i used `sudo` but could not open.
After doing `./ file.exe` i got this error -

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in �.: (): IL_0002: brtrue.s  IL_0006


[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in �.: (): IL_0002: brtrue.s  IL_0006
```

How to solve this error??

Comment: i think it is not partition related issue,

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: What's the output of `file ./file.exe` . In your question you have a space between `./` and `file.exe` which may be a typo here, but that won't work. What is the executable? Is it a windows one, or dotnet?

Comment: the executable is for windows and mac

Comment: that was typing mistake, i did `./file.exe`

Comment: in command line i changed the permission to 777 and it changed, but when in the file's properties its is showing i have only read and write permission.

Comment: You can not run a Windows executable on a Ubuntu OS. You just tried to put diesel fuel in a gas engine and complained it would not run.